# Unexpected behavior with Get-Job when only one job running

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm new to Powershell and I'm having an issue with the Get-Job command.  In my script, I'm testing out multi-threading and am doing something like:

```
$Program = {
    "Thread " + $args[0];
    Start-Sleep 5;
}
Start-Job $Program -ArgumentList @($i) | Out-Null
```

The Start-Job call is actually in a loop in which I'm creating multiple jobs.  Below this, I have:

```
Get-Job
"Jobs Running: " + $(Get-Job -State Running).count
```

If there are multiple jobs running, I will get output like:

```
Id              Name            State      HasMoreData     Location             Command
--              ----            -----      -----------     --------             -------
2201            Job2201         Running    True            localhost            ...
2199            Job2199         Running    True            localhost            ...
2197            Job2197         Running    True            localhost            ...
2195            Job2195         Running    True            localhost            ...
2193            Job2193         Completed  True            localhost            ...
2191            Job2191         Completed  True            localhost            ...
2189            Job2189         Completed  True            localhost            ...
2187            Job2187         Completed  True            localhost            ...
Jobs Running: 4
```

But if there is only one job running, it seems that `$(Get-Job -State Running).count` isn't returning anything:

```
Id              Name            State      HasMoreData     Location             Command
--              ----            -----      -----------     --------             -------
2207            Job2207         Running    True            localhost            ...
Jobs Running:
```

As you can see, there is one job running, but `$(Get-Job -State Running).count` doesn't return anything.  Any idea what's happening here?  To me, it looks like that if there are multiple jobs, `$(Get-Job -State Running)` returns a collection of jobs which has the .count property, whereas if there is only one job, it returns just that job, and doesn't have the .count property.  If this is the case (or if I'm doing something wrong), what command should I be using to get my expected result of `$(Get-Job -State Running).count == 1`?

Comment: You're seeing a bit PSH "helpfulness" (helpful often, but sometimes not): If an expression (including a pipeline) returns a single object you get that object, if there are zero or more than one objects then an array is returned. Therefore if only one job exists `Get-Job` returns that job object which does not have a `Count` (or `Length`) property. Fix for when you always want an array is not force an array by using `@(…)` (eg. `$jobs = @(get-job)`).

Comment: So if there is only one job, `$jobs` is an array containing that job.  If there are multiple jobs, Since `Get-Job` would already return an array, wouldn't I expect `$jobs` to be an array containing an array of jobs?  Perhaps there is more PSH "helpfulness" at work here?

Comment: No: if there is *one* job then `$jobs` will be that job object; otherwise it will be an array of jobs. Wrap in `@(...)` to always get an array.

Comment: I understand what happens.  I was just pointing out that it's a little weird that `@(Get-Job)` will always be a one dimensional array regardless of whether `Get-Job` returns an array or an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using Measure-Object

```
$(Get-Job -State Running | Measure-Object).count
```

Answer (score 2):

In PS 2.0 `count` only works on arrays. When `Get-Job` only returns one job, it returns it as an OBJECT, not an array. To make it work, you could e.g. force `Get-Job` to always return an array by using `@(code)` .  Try this:

```
$Program = {
    "Thread " + $args[0];
    Start-Sleep 5;
}
Start-Job $Program -ArgumentList @($i) | Out-Null

Get-Job
"Jobs Running: " + $(@(Get-Job -State Running).count)
```